# how to pass different set of props to a vue child

Tags: vue.js

I have a parent vue component consisting of a list of items when clicked on an item a edit part child component becomes visible, on the mounted method of the child the parameters are set for edit however when clicking a different item the mounted method on the child is of course not called again, leaving the same state visible how can i reset the child?, the content of the child is sent using props, parent roughly

```
    <div v-for="user in users" :key="user.id" @click=editUser(user)>{{user.name}}
</div>
      <EditUser props="editedUser" edit=true v-if=editingUser

 method: editUser(user){
   this.editingUser=true
   this.editedUser.name=user.name;
 }
```

and the child roughly:

```
mounted:function(){
   this.name=editedUser.name;
}
<input type="text" v-model="name"
```

Comment: Please show some code so we can understand and answer better.  Also when you say "..when clicking on a different item..." You are saying you want to click on a different item in the parent and update the child with that items props, right?

Comment: yes, basically a very simple crud

Comment: You're probably not—or, incorrectly—declaring the props in your `EditUser` component. In that case there is no reactivity and the child component won't respond to the update on the parent. If that's not the problem, you probably don't set `name` on update of the `editedUser` props. `mounted` won't be called on props updates; so, you will need to define a watcher for this. Either way: post executable code please.

Comment: I work with Vue.js every day, and do exactly what you are describing without any issues at all.  Since you are showing your code only roughly, it is not possible to see where your issue is.  But you are most certainly not passing your props properly in the example above.   The line `props="editUser"` if it does anything, is only passing the actual string "editUser"  certainly not a object.

Comment: P.S.  Please read the documentation examples here  https://vuejs.org/v2/api/#props   and here  https://vuejs.org/v2/guide/components.html#Passing-Data-to-Child-Components-with-Props   Pay special attention to the use ov `v-bind`  in `  v-bind:title="post.title"`  it goes without saying the the shorthand for `v-bind` is simply the colon by itself.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The functionality you are describing is simple and if you are passing the props correctly the child should be reactive and update without any issues. With a quick look I don't see what is causing your issue. The best I can do at this point is to show you a simple example of something like you describe working.

**Edit:  Now I see on second look that you are trying to pass your props like `props='something'`  I am not sure if you are just naming your prop "props" or what there, but typically you pass a prop with with a kabab-case `:my-prop='someObject'` and notice that it is using ':' the short hand "v-bind" on that prop as well. Then in your child component you receive the props by doing `props: ['myProp']` (use camelcase).**

I created this example while you were updating your code.  So it is a bit different, but the principle is the same.   Notice I am passing the `item` into the function with a button click and that is updating the prop that is set on the "edit" component

```
<button @click="edit(item)">edit</button>
//....
<edit-component v-if='showEdit' :item-data="editData">
```

https://jsfiddle.net/skribe/m60xof4b/

Comment: hmm on second look you are not passing the data around using props and since it is all one big component there is no need for that but in my case the edit mode is a bit more complicated and i would like to re-use that on an add component or edit myself component as well i will try to add my code somewhere for examination

Comment: No in fact  there are separate components, and I am passing the the data using props. Are you thinking this because they are not in separate files?  You can in fact define any number of components using `Vue.component` in a single file.  **Look again in the script section.** ....

Comment: The part that defines the child component is.. `Vue.component('edit-component', ....  props:['itemData'],...`  and the prop it is receiving is the `itemData`  its template is bound to the element with the id 'child.`  The parent component is the default app itself but it could just as easily be defined separately as well.  Here for sake of argument is the same jsfiddle from above reformated to use the main app instance with two components in it.  The parent and the child.    https://jsfiddle.net/skribe/w6v3cxrk/

Comment: yes using your code i found my error, before setting the item i wanted to edit i created a copy of it to prevent the 2-way binding, as i find it confusing if the parent is updated as well without an explicit save action, but now i had to first reset my object to {} and then it works